# An amenable group containing a wreath product of itself

Tags: gr.group-theory

Does there exist a finitely generated amenable group $G$ which contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G\wr\mathbb{Z} = \bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} G \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I thought a wreath product involved products, not sums, e.g., $(\prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} G) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$. I guess you mean "restricted wreath product": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product#Definition ?

Comment: Can't you just iteratively replace $G$ with $G\wr\mathbb{Z}$ and take a direct limit?

Comment: Sorry, only just saw that you stipulated "finitely generated".

Comment: @ToddTrimble, that convention is not very firm.  See, for instance, the Lamplighter Group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group .  In geometric and combinatorial group theory, where we are mostly interested in finitely generated groups, we almost always use direct sums.

Comment: Thompson's group $F$ contains $F \wr \mathbb{Z}$, so you just have to determine whether $F$ is amenable or not. Okay, maybe it is not a fair indication...

Comment: @ToddTrimble that's why I included a clarification, it's also clear why finitely generated is necessary. Thompson's group is an interesting one, possibly it suggests that this construction is itself on the limits of what it manageable inside an amenable group.